# ODBC driver with two versions of PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed php 5.6 along side an already existing php 5.5

All seems to be working fine except for connecting to sqlserver

This is my test php script:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"$DB", "UID"=>"$DBUSER", "PWD"=>"$DBPASS");

$cn = sqlsrv_connect($DBSERVER, $connectionInfo);
$strErrors = getSQLErrors();
if ($strErrors != "")
    die($strErrors);

sqlsrv_close($cn);

function getSQLErrors($ignoreWarnings = false)
{
        $retVal = "";
        $err = sqlsrv_errors();
        if ($err)
        {
                foreach( $err as $error )
                {
                        if (!$ignoreWarnings || ($ignoreWarnings && $error['SQLSTATE'] != 1000)) // ignore warnings
                                $retVal .= "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE'].". Code: ".$error[ 'code'].". Message: ".$error[ 'message']."\r\n\r\n";
                }
        }

        return $retVal;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
SQLSTATE: IMSSP. Code: -49. Message: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL t
o download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

SQLSTATE: IM002. Code: 0. Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I already have the following in my ext folder and in my php.ini:

```
php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

I have path environment variable pointing to my 5.6 php.

The relevant paths in the php.ini file all point to the 5.6 version also.

Is there something else I need to be aware of?  Can anyone help me out before I pull all my hair out?

Comment: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712)

Comment: Yes - already done that and it was there anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the link provided in the error message is not the one I need.

The file I need is msodbcsql.msi

which can be found at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

As an added note.  PHP 7 requires a version of the Windows ODBC driver that is not available for win 2008 R2